# R sample row from matrix and set numeric values to 0

Tags: r, matrix, sample

I want to sample a row from a matrix and then set all **numeric** values in that sampled row to 0.

## Data

```
matrix = structure(c('Sp1', 'Sp2', 'Sp3', 'Sp4', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "col1", "col2", "col3")))
```

## Calc sums

```
matrix = `colnames<-`(cbind(matrix, rowSums(`class<-`(matrix[,-1], 'numeric'))),c(colnames(matrix), 'Sums'))
```

## Output

```
           col1 col2 col3 Sums
[1,] "Sp1" "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
[2,] "Sp2" "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
[3,] "Sp3" "1"  "1"  "0"  "2" 
[4,] "Sp4" "0"  "1"  "1"  "2"
```

So it creates a matrix then calculates the Sums. Now I want it to sample a random row, set all values in **numeric part** to 0 and recalculate the Sums.

So far I got this:

```
sample <- matrix[sample(nrow(matrix),size=1,replace=FALSE),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done this by either converting to 'data.frame' or using the first column as rownames to keep the matrix as numeric.  If you have multiple class in the dataset, it would be better to have 'data.frame' because 'matrix' can have only a single class.  Even if there is a single element that is character, the whole matrix will be converted to 'character' class.  In the below example, a matrix is created with 'sps' as the row names.  By doing this, we can make the code simple instead of converting back to 'numeric'.

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,0, 1), nrow=4, ncol=3, 
         dimnames=list(paste0('sp', 1:4), paste0('col', 1:3)))
m2 <- cbind(m1, Sums=rowSums(m1))

m1[sample(nrow(m1), 1, replace=FALSE),] <- 0
cbind(m1, Sums=rowSums(m1))
```

Or an elegant option suggested by @nicola

```
m2*sample(c(rep(1,nrow(m2)-1),0))
```

About naming the object as 'matrix',

```
library(fortunes)
fortune('dog')
```

> Firstly, don't call your matrix 'matrix'. Would you call your dog 'dog'?
>   Anyway, it might clash with the function 'matrix'.
>      -- Barry Rowlingson
>         R-help (October 2004)

Comment: +1, especially for explaining why he should have used row names. Anyway, another solution could be `m2*sample(c(rep(1,nrow(m2)-1),0))`.